# Replace square brackets of array with curly in javascript

Tags: arrays, json, javascript-objects, curly-braces

I am stuck with this problem, this is what i have:

```
const data =  [
  {
    "barcode": "28738212",
    "_id": "JEyz9x1ydoPOLpMn7WXHMUTijo"
  },
  {
    "barcode": "9897876653",
    "_id": "RTxvdx3lYWwKcbTOlrbhngWdWb"
  }
]
```

and I want it to have no any square brackets for a REST API POST like this

```
 const data =  {
    "barcode": "28738212",
    "_id": "JEyz9x1ydoPOLpMn7WXHMUTijo"
  },
  {
    "barcode": "9897876653",
    "_id": "RTxvdx3lYWwKcbTOlrbhngWdWb"
  }
```

what i tried but did not work

```
 const braces = {};
    
    for (const {_id, barcode} of data) {
      braces = {_id, barcode}
    }
    console.log(braces);

//either syntax error or only return the first data
```

Comment: `what i tried but did not work` ... what you seem to want here isn't valid JavaScript code _or_ valid JSON.  Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution i can think of it to do string manipulations. So you'd have to,

```
var str =  String(data);
var newData = str.replace("[", "");
newData = newData.replace("]", "");
data = JSON.parse(newData);
```